# ZeroMQ in R, how to close socket

Tags: r, zeromq

**how can I close an opened zmq socket in R?**

```
  port = 1111
  zmq_context <- init.context()
  zmq_service.socket <- init.socket(zmq_context,"ZMQ_REQ")
  connect.socket(zmq_service.socket, paste("tcp://127.0.0.1:", port, sep = ""))
```

As I see it, I can just remove the object and expect garbage collector to waste it.

```
  rm(zmq_service.socket, zmq_context)
```

Comment: Can't see any bindings for the socket's `close` method in https://github.com/armstrtw/rzmq . :-/

Comment: I have added an [issue](https://github.com/armstrtw/rzmq/issues/17) there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It  has been fixed by developer. See [gihub issue](https://github.com/armstrtw/rzmq/issues/17).

```
disconnect.socket <- function(socket, address) {
    invisible(.Call("disconnectSocket", socket, address, PACKAGE="rzmq"))
}
```